# Windows 7 will not start with SSD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, sata

I have a Windows 7 Desktop, with a 320GB HDD. I recently found an old SSD in my garage, and out of curiosity tried to connect it to my PC to see if it still worked.

After plugging in the SSD to SATA 1 (the HDD is in SATA 0) on my computer, I start up, but for some reason, it won't let me boot from the SSD or the HDD, and I know that without the SSD the computer starts up fine. Right now with both drives my computer just freezes at the "Starting Windows" screen.

Does anyone know what is wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like a bad SSD, probably logic board that Windows is trying to initialize.

Comment: A bad drive if it failed to intialize would cause this problem.  Sounds like you found a paper weight

Comment: Ah, so my SSD is bad. But do you know why won't the normal drive work with the ssd plugged in?

Comment: We just told you.  Windows is trying to intialize the SSD, its not able to do that, it keeps trying to do that, rinse and repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `AthomSfere` and `Ramhound` mentioned in the comments, the drive's logic board might be bad. If you have an [external HDD enclosure](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Delectronics&field-keywords=hard%20drive%20enclosure&rh=n%3A172282%2Ck%3Ahard%20drive%20enclosure) you can try plugging in the SSD after windows boots, to make sure it's actually dead and not detectable by the system.